# Is there an advantage to using contextlib.closing when making a request using urllib.request.urlopen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, contextmanager

To illustrate my question, here is a basic request that doesn't use `contextlib`:

```
    import urllib.request

    url = "http://www.example.com/"

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        raw_data = response.read()
```

And the same request using `contextlib`:

```
    import contextlib
    import urllib.request


    url = "http://www.example.com/"

    with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url)) as response:
        raw_data = response.read()
```

As far as I can tell these two requests have the same results: the data is retrieved, the request is automatically closed upon the completion of the code block, and `raw_data` is accessible even after the request is closed. When making a request using `urllib.request.urlopen`, then, is there an advantage to using `contextlib.closing` or is it redundant? Is one approach more Pythonic and/or more common?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`contextlib.closing()` is useful for turning objects that support a `close()` method into a context manager that can be used with a `with` statement.

It adds no value to objects that already support the context manager protocol.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html) for `urllib.request.urlopen()` explains:

> For ftp, file, and data urls and requests explicitly handled by legacy URLopener and FancyURLopener classes, this function returns a urllib.response.addinfourl object which can work as context manager

So in this case, there is no point in wrapping it in a `closing` function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear response. I'll read the docs more-thoroughly next time before asking the question.